# Apache2.5 Ubuntu22 upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Hi have followed [this](https://haneefputtur.com/upgrade-apache-to-latest-version-in-ubuntu-server-20.html), restarted apache2, rebooted the instance and still 2.4.54.  Is it as simple as getting the latest and untar it into the existing directory?  Please advise.

Comment: In general questions/problems regarding the usability of or inaccuracies in HOWTO's and manuals should be addressed to their author and not posted on ServerFault. - Alternatively read our  [guide to writing good questions](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and post an [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) question that contains sufficient details/errors/configuration-settings about **your setup** to provide you with a good solution, rather than confusing the issue with potential issues in both that guide and/or how accurately it was followed.

Comment: In general you should never just "untar" something in Linux systems, especially when it comes to services that have a lot of dependencies. If you just replace the files from the package, the next upgrade will overwrite them. Also installing newer versions in the correct places should be very carefully examined, as programs tend to have vulnerabilities and you'll lose the distro provided patches to them and it's up to you to keep the software up to date. This is especially important with Internet facing services, such as the Apache web server.